# Firebase Storage: Does the Download URL for a storage reference change if the data stored at that reference is changed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am storing profile images in firebase storage for all registered users and storing the download url:

```
storageReference.getDownloadUrl()
```

as an attribute of that user in the database. If the said user updates his image at the same storage reference, does that mean I've to update the download url as well or does it remain the same regardless of the updation?
I'm not sure what other details I need to give here so feel free to ask for more information, Thanks.

Comment: Do you change the profile image name every time it's changed?

Comment: no the name remains the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you replace the file in Firebase Storage it changes permission and also the public download URL. That means, as you asumed, that you need to update the donwloadURL every time you change the image even if the filename and path stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another solution that worked for me:

Make the profile images publicly accessible for everyone, in that case the token is ignored even if it's not matching and the image can be displayed.

⚠️ Depends if you can afford to have the data publicly accessible by anyone, which profile images can satisfy.

I give credit to stayfoolish from this thread:
https://forums.appgyver.com/t/firebase-storage-non-changing-download-link-possible/9782/4