# Firebase storage download url token expire

Tags: firebase

is there posibility that token expire in downloadUrl of firebase storage. I cant access my file after some time. I see access denied. file path is like:
[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/m*****-dev.appspot.com/o/panel-photo?alt=media&token=fasdfjıo](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/m*****-dev.appspot.com/o/panel-photo?alt=media&token=fasdfj%C4%B1o) fjıosadf

Answer (score 3):

Download URLs generated by the Firebase SDKs don't expire after a certain time. While you can manually revoke their token, that is not time-based.

If you need URLs that provide public access for a certain amount of time, have a look a the [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) that the Google Cloud SDKs can generate. You will have to do that from a server though as those SDKs require full access to your bucket/project.

Comment: thanks for your answer, then why I might be getting permission denied error after a certain amount of time, have you any idea?

Comment: If you want help troubleshooting a concrete problem you have, you should post a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem (rather than how to accomplish something as you now did).

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same issue and figured is was caused by files being overwritten. If you have an old download URL and upload a file with the same path, then the old URL will no longer be valid.

Also have a look at [this question about download URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272398/firebase-storage-does-the-download-url-for-a-storage-reference-change-if-the-da).

In our case it was due to name collisions as people would upload the same file in different places and the files would end up in the same bucket with the same name. Old references would become invalid, even though the actual bytes of the file would remain unchanged.